# react-apollo getClient is undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

There appears to be an error with how I'm using react-apollo. Following the docs, I am attempting to make a basic query with Apollo. This is the error I get in the browser when on the Review page. It appears that this.getClient is undefined and unable to call watchQuery.

```
react-apollo.browser.umd.js:417 Uncaught TypeError: this.getClient(...).watchQuery is not a function
at GraphQL.createQuery (react-apollo.browser.umd.js:417)
at GraphQL.setInitialProps (react-apollo.browser.umd.js:404)
at GraphQL.componentWillMount (react-apollo.browser.umd.js:260)
etc...
```

Here is the code for the Review page. I create a Review React Component, declare a graphql-tag that calls the userInfo query, and export the graphql tag connected to the Review page below.

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

class Review extends React.Component {...}

const userInfoQuery = gql`
query userInfoQuery{
  userInfo {
    _id
    email
    name {
      first
      last
    }
    isVerified
  }
}`

const ReviewWithData = graphql(userInfoQuery)(Review)
export default ReviewWithData;
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from the code you posted. Do you have more relevant code?
Also, did you use the ApolloProvider component? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/setup.html#creating-provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I was defining the wrong client in the root index.js file. So for the code below, the client I was exporting was not actually the correct Apollo client. So the variable `client` on the sixth import was importing some other functions. Lesson learned! Should have been more careful!

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';

import App from './containers/app';
import client from './services/Apollo'

const CustomerFrontendApp = (
  <ApolloProvider client={BitsyApollo.client}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

render(BitsyCustomerFrontendApp, document.getElementById('root'));